# Trying to run SP in excel (vba macro) multiple times

Tags: vba, excel, stored-procedures

I am trying to run a SP inside a function in an excel macro (button):

```
Sub Button13_Click()
    Call exec_sp_GetLoan_CFM_Info_by_customerID("B3", 2, 1)
    Call exec_sp_GetLoan_CFM_Info_by_customerID("B24", 3, 1)
    Call exec_sp_GetLoan_CFM_Info_by_customerID("B45", 4, 1)
    Call exec_sp_GetLoan_CFM_Info_by_customerID("B66", 5, 1)
    Call exec_sp_GetLoan_CFM_Info_by_customerID("B86", 6, 1)
End Sub
```

The SP returns a single row every time, and I'm trying to write a row with every result set. What happens is that I'm getting a single row in the spreadsheet, for example, as it is shown above, I would only get row 2 with result set for custID from B3. If I comment out the first line, I would only get row 3 with results for custID from B24, and so on. I can never get more than 1 row, and I don't understand why (I'm completely new to vb and excel macros). Can anybody explain what's happening? This is happening even if I don't clear any rows... thank you!

Update: If I set up separate buttons for each 'Call' of the function, it runs fine...

```
Function exec_sp_GetLoan_CFM_Info_by_customerID(custIDcell As String, stRow As Integer, stCol As Integer)
 Dim con As ADODB.Connection
 Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
 Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
 Dim WSP1 As Worksheet
 Set con = New ADODB.Connection
 Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
 Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

 Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
 Application.StatusBar = "Contacting SQL Server..."

' Log in
 con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;"
 cmd.ActiveConnection = con

 ' Set up the parameter for the Stored Procedure
 cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("custID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8, Range(custIDcell).Text)

 Application.StatusBar = "Running stored procedure..."
 cmd.CommandText = "sp_GetLoan_CFM_Info_by_customerID"
 Set rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)

 Set WSP1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CIFInfo")
 WSP1.Activate

 'clear row
 WSP1.Rows(stRow).Clear

 If rs.EOF = False Then WSP1.Cells(stRow, stCol).CopyFromRecordset rs

 'cmd.Parameters("custID").Value = Range("B24").Text

 'cleanup
 rs.Close
 Set rs = Nothing
 Set cmd = Nothing

 con.Close
 Set con = Nothing

 Application.StatusBar = "Data successfully updated."

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginner's (Excel) mistake... after calling the function with the SP for the first time, the active worksheet gets changed to a different one from the input, so subsequent calls are done with an empty input parameter!! 
That wasn't obvious from the post.. sorry!!